# Overflowed By with DropdownButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dropdownbutton

**Background:** Hello. I have just started learning Flutter and I have run into an Overflowed By error when trying to create a dropdown menu in the top left corner of the app I'm building.

**Question:**
How can I accurately format a dropdown menu in the top left corner of my app. I want the menu to be flush with the side of the left screen and the icon in the symmetrical opposite position relative to the rightmost icon as pictured in the attached image. Before, I had an IconButton instead of a DropdownButton, and the IconButton was itself,  automatically positioned correctly. I would also like to correctly center the menu icon because, as you can see, it is slightly off center-vertical.

**Code:**

```
appBar: AppBar(
      leading: DropdownButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu, color: colorPalette.chooseColor('black')), items: [DropdownMenuItem(child: Text('Events'),],),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text('Some Title', style: TextStyle(color: colorPalette.chooseColor('black'), fontSize: 23),),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined,  
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            // do something
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need add **drawer** property, inside the Scaffold. And delete **leading** from your Appbar.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
  body: Center(child: Text('My Page!')),
  drawer: Drawer(
  child: ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
  //here you can customize the menu with the widgets you want. Example:
    ListTile(
    title: Text("Item 1"),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
       ),
     ],
    ),
  ),
```

Nice code!

Comment: Doesn't exactly answer the question but great alternative! Thank you :) Not even sure if using a DropdownButton is possible?

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem to wrap the contents of the drawer. I only want to have 4 clickable words in there but the drawer is relatively huge.

Comment: @MAF please check my answer below

Comment: I think, the answer of @Bach, resolve your question. Try with his code.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use the `leading` attribute of the `AppBar` all the time. We can place the `Dropdown` in the same position without it overflowing by using `title` only. This way it gives you lots of flexibility in customizing your `AppBar` widget:

```dart
AppBar(
      leadingWidth: 0,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: 0,
            child: DropdownButton(
                // ... other lines
                ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              'Some Title',
              // ... other lines
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.map_outlined)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```